# Storing numbers greater than a value in an array into another array

Tags: c++, arrays, list, sorting

I am a beginner C++ programmer so I apologize for my messy code. I have an assignment where I need to create a function that passes a list/array created by the user to print out all integers that are greater than 10 and the count. When the user enters a negative number, the program will end and print whatever the user entered, if anything. Part of my solution so far consists of:

```
void PrintGreaterThan(const int list[]) {
    int index, finalCount, greaterThan[MAX_SIZE];
    finalCount = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < MAX_SIZE; index++) {
        if (list[index] > 10) {
            greaterThan[index] = list[index];
            finalCount++;
        }

    }
    cout << "The list contains " << finalCount <<
        " non-negative integer(s) that are \ngreater than 10 as follows: " << 
    endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < finalCount; ++count) {
        cout << greaterThan[count] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
}
```

My program is able to take in user input such as ``1 2 3 4 5 -1, and print out nothing, which is correct. If I enter `20 30 40 50 2 3 4 -1`, the program will only display numbers over `10` and correct count of numbers over `10`, which is also correct. But when I enter say for example, `30 40 2 3 20 40`, the program will print out `30 40` and then error values. I feel like I am missing something ... Maybe I am implementing this incorrectly? I thought about maybe a method of skipping the element in the array if the number is `10` and under? There's different parts to the program that is why I did not post the whole thing in case there's too much unnecessary detail. Thank you .

Comment: You have an error/bug here at `greaterThan[index] = list[index];` - `index` is for `list`, not for `greaterThan` in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same `index` as the index into both `list` and `greaterThan`. Which means that when a number is not greater than `10`, you skip that index in `greaterThan`, and that element is left uninitialized. And when you're printing the results, you're only going up to `finalCount`, even though you filled in higher elements of `greaterThan`.

You should use a different variable for the index into `greaterThan`. You can use the `finalCount` variable, since it's incremented exactly as you want.

```
    if (list[index] > 10) {
        greaterThan[finalCount] = list[index];
        finalCount++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was the exact answer!